# Apache camel not mapping set parameters on sql update

Tags: sql, apache-camel

I'm using this query to update my table using apache camel component but ths MSG property is not mapped by camel while REQUEST_ID is mapped and i get Oracl syntax error

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException:
> PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04044: procédure, fonction,
> package ou type interdits ici

My route :

```java
       from("select * from source_table")
       .split(body()).parallelProcessing()
                       .process(exchange -> {
        LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap body = (LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap) exchange.getIn().getBody();
exchange.setProperty("MSG", "VAL1");
exchange.setProperty("REQUEST_ID", body.get("REQUEST_ID");
})
                
   
      .to("sql:UPDATE destination_table set  STATUS ='P', MSG=:#${property.MSG} WHERE REQUEST_ID =:#${property.REQUEST_ID}");
```

Comment: I use this in a processor befor calling sql endpoint       
exchange.setProperty("MSG", "-");
exchange.setProperty("REQUEST_ID" body.get("REQUEST_ID"));

Comment: yes i use both MSG and REQUEST_ID

Comment: Yes the MSG is hardcoded and i get the same Error the MSG is not mapped while REQUEST_ID is OK, i posted the route